# Resize all images stored in array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I stored images read through `cv2.imread` in an array `masks`. The shape of the array is `(10, 5248, 7936, 3) (10 images, image height, image width, 3 channels)`.

I am now trying to copy this array but with every image resized to the values `monitor_h` and `monitor_w`. Here is what I have:

```
resized_masks = np.empty([masks.shape[0], monitor_h, monitor_w, masks.shape[3]])

for i in range(masks.shape[0]):
    resized_masks[i] = cv2.resize(np.copy(masks[i]), (monitor_w, monitor_h))
```

But the images I get from `cv2.imshow` are black and white. Something must have happened with the channels. Any leads?

Comment: have tried with `interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA` in `cv2.resize()`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat This doesn't change anything

Comment: could you tell more about the how you specified `monitor_w` and `monitor_h`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat `monitor_w = 1080` and `monitor_h = 700`

Comment: You made your output array have a float dtype. You need to add `dtype=masks.dtype`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why your images are coming out black and white, let's step through the code.

```
resized_masks = np.empty([masks.shape[0], monitor_h, monitor_w, masks.shape[3]])
```

This line creates an array of type `np.float` by default.

```
resized_masks[i] = cv2.resize(np.copy(masks[i]), (monitor_w, monitor_h))
```

This line assigns the result of `cv2.resize` to a slice of `resized_masks`.

Your original images, and therefore the result of `cv2.resize`, are presumably of type `np.uint8`. The assignment casts the values into `float`s to put them in the buffer. The cast is fine in and of itself: `5` converts to `5.0`, `255` converts to `255.0`. The problem is that `float` values are interpreted as being clipped to the range `[0.0, 1.0]`, not `[0.0, 255.0]`. You therefore end up with images that are effectively all zeros and ones, even though they contain what looks like the correct values.

You can verify that the values are correct by displaying

```
resized_masks.astype(masks.dtype)
```

This is not a real fix. The real fix is to start with the correct output type:

```
resized_masks = np.empty((masks.shape[0], monitor_h, monitor_w, masks.shape[3]), dtype=masks.dtype)
```

Note that it's conventional to use tuples for shapes, not lists, but it doesn't matter functionally.

Now let's look at why your [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60738223/2988730) worked.

```
resized_masks = list(resized_masks)
```

This creates a Python list of references to each sub-array. Since you are really slicing, they will still point to a contiguous buffer under the hood, but the important thing is that each `resized_masks[i]` is a separate reference, not a slice into the same array object.

```
resized_masks[i] = list(cv2.resize(np.copy(masks[i]), (monitor_w, monitor_h)))
```

Since `resized_masks` is a list containing references, this is now assigning the result of `cv2.resize` to the `i`th list element, not assigning the contents into an appropriately sized slice. You don't need the `list` wrapper here, as it introduces an unnecessary dimension.

```
resized_masks = np.asarray(resized_masks)
```

This just recombines the list into an array, since all the elements are of the right size (although you will see an extra unit dimension, as mentioned above). As you can imagine this solution is extremely inefficient. On top of the fact that you are going to and from lists and allocating multiple unnecessary buffers, you are also discarding the original `np.empty` array without using it.

Your patch is roughly equivalent to doing

```
resized_masks = np.array([cv2.resize(np.copy(mask), (monitor_w, monitor_h)) for mask in masks])
```

I don't recommend doing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround to my problem, but I'm still interested to know what made the images go black and white.

Here is what I came up with :

```
resized_masks = np.empty([masks.shape[0], monitor_h, monitor_w, masks.shape[3]])
resized_masks = list(resized_masks)

for i in range(len(resized_masks)):
    resized_masks[i] = list(cv2.resize(np.copy(masks[i]), (monitor_w, monitor_h)))

resized_masks = np.asarray(resized_masks)
```

Comment: I'd add this as an update to your question rather than an answer. I'll post a complete answer momentarily.